# Javaconfig bean overiding does not take in account added @DependsOn

Tags: spring, javabeans

While overrding a Javaconfig Bean by extending the original @Configuration class, I would like to add a @DependsOn for the new Bean definition.

However, this depends-on seems not to be taken in account. here is a TestCase reproducing my issues:

```
public class SpringTest {

@Test
public void testDependsOnTakenInAccount() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx2 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AConfig.class, CConfig.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("overriden", ctx2.getBean("bean"));
}

@Configuration
public static class AConfig {

    @Bean
    public Object bean() {
        return "not overriden";
    }

}

@Configuration
public static class CConfig extends AConfig {

    protected boolean isInitialized = false;

    @Bean
    public Void doInit() {
        isInitialized = true;

        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("doInit")
    public Object bean() {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not initialized");
        }

        return "overriden";
    }

}

}
```

Is this an expected behavior? If yes, how can I add dependency while overriding a bean?

Comment: After some time without comments, I will fire a jira issue to see if really is a bug or not.

Comment: Hi Jose, I created https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10992, but there is no answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Jose Luis Martin, this has been confirmed as a bug by Spring team.

I've workarounded it with:

```
@DependsOn("doInit")
@Bean
public Void notOverridingBean() {
    return null;
}

@Bean
public Object bean(Object notOverridingBean) {
    return "overriden";
}
```

an alternative is to override the bean in another @Configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

For me seems like a bug.

When overriding a `@Bean`  factory method in a Configuration class, the parent `BeanDefinition` wins and get registered on the `BeanFactory` overriding the child one.

So you cannot configure the bean with annotaions (because it will be overriden).

The following Test result on

> expected:<[doInit]> but was:<[otherBean]>

```
@RunWith(JUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DependOnTest {

    @Test
    public void testBeanDefinitionOverriding() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        BeanDefinition bd = ctx.getBeanDefinition("bean");
        Assert.assertEquals("doInit", bd.getDependsOn()[0]);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ParentConfig {

        @Bean
        @DependsOn("otherBean")
        public String bean() {
            return "not overriden";
        }

        @Bean
        public String otherBean() {
            return "otherBean";
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config extends ParentConfig {

        @Bean
        public String doInit() {
            return "doInit";
        }

        @Bean
        @DependsOn("doInit")
        public String bean() {
            return "overriding";
        }

    }
}
```

I think that problem start on ConfigurationClassParser:

```
    // recursively process the configuration class and its superclass hierarchy
    do {
        metadata = doProcessConfigurationClass(configClass, metadata);
    }
    while (metadata != null);
```

That result on overriden method added to `CongurationClass.beanMethods`

It could be fixed checking if the beanMethod was already added from a superclass in `ConfigurationClass.addBeanMethod()`

```
public void addBeanMethod(BeanMethod method) {
    // Check if already added a bean method from superclass 
    for (BeanMethod beanMethod : beanMethods) {
        if (beanMethod.getMetadata().getMethodName().equals(method.getMetadata().getMethodName()) &&
                !(beanMethod.getMetadata().getDeclaringClassName()).equals(method.getMetadata().getDeclaringClassName()))

            // log and return.
            return;
        }

    this.beanMethods.add(method);
}
```